# Not getting response from server. Angularjs, nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, web-development-server

I'm trying to get a "success" or "failure" response from my server to client. The server is being implemented in node.js in express framework and the client in angularjs.

Here is the server side node.js part:

```
connection.connect();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'views', 'login.html'));
});
router.get('/login', function(req,res)
{

  console.log("Username:"+req.query.username);
  console.log("Password:"+req.query.password);

  var user = req.query.username;
  var pass = req.query.password

  connection.query("select * from user where login_name = ?", user, function(err, rows, fields) {
                     if (!err){
                        if(user==rows[0].login_name && pass==rows[0].pass){
                            console.log("success");
                            res.json({status: 200});
                        }
                     }
                     else
                         console.log('Error while performing Query.', err);
                     });
```

and here is the angularjs part:

```
<form name="login">
    <div class="login" ng-app="loginPage" ng-controller="loginController">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username" ng-model="uname" name="userid"><br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="pword" name="pswrd"><br>
        <!--<input type="button" ng-click="login();" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>-->
        <button ng-click="login();">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script language="javascript">
    var app = angular.module('loginPage', []);
    app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http) {
        console.log("inside controller");

        $scope.login = function() {
            console.log("inside the login function");
            console.log($scope.uname);

            var verify = $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/login' +
                '',
                params: { username: $scope.uname, password: $scope.pword }
            }).then(
                    function successful(response) {
                        $scope.theResponse = response.data;
                        window.open("./team_list.html")
                    }, function unsuccessful(response) {
                        alert('Wrong username/password.');
                        $scope.theResponse = response.data;
                    });
        }
    })
</script>
```

I try to type in "test" for username and "test" for pw on the login page on the browser because that is what I have entered in my sql database. Specifically I'm not sure why the login page doesn't link to the team_list page that I have specified the path for.

I'm not really sure why it's not working. If I'm supposed to be using json differently, I would appreciate more help because I am not very familiar with it.

Comment: why are you assigning http call to variable "verify"

Comment: what are you getting from server side? are you able to get user details with query?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the routing in the NodeJS side is wrong. The `/login` should come first. Else everything will be served by the `'/'` route.

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {

      console.log("Username:" + req.query.username);
      console.log("Password:" + req.query.password);

      var user = req.query.username;
      var pass = req.query.password

      connection.query("select * from user where login_name = ?", user, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (!err) {
          if (user == rows[0].login_name && pass == rows[0].pass) {
            console.log("success");
            res.json({
              status: 200
            });
          }
        } else
          console.log('Error while performing Query.', err);
      });
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../', 'views', 'login.html'));
});
```

Comment: #Arun .. I don't think your answer is appropriate.. Here, nothing to do with positioning of code ....

Answer (score 0):

Check your console  you can even figure out the problem from there.
Shortcuts for console

[shortcut keys for opening different browsers's Console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

**do it like this** :

```
connection.query("select * from user where login_name = ?", user, function(err, rows, fields) {
     if (!err){
        if(user==rows[0].login_name && pass==rows[0].pass){
            console.log("success");
            res.send(200);
        }
     }
     else{
         console.log('Error while performing Query.', err);
         res.send(401);
     }
 });
```

**Actually, you should send Error or Success code like 200 or 401.**

And use 
`res.send(ErrorCode)` or `res.sendStatus(ErrorCode)` and it'll autmatically do it for you at client side like below :

```
<script language="javascript">
    var app = angular.module('loginPage', []);
    app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http, $window) {
        console.log("inside controller");
        $scope.login = function() {
            console.log("inside the login function");
            console.log($scope.uname);
            $http.get('/login').then(function (success) {
                $window.alert('Success');
            }, function (error) {
                $window.alert('Wrong username/password.');
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```